# How to send Outlook email without prompt in Access using macros?

Tags: ms-access, vba

How to send Outlook email without prompt in Access using macros? For example in the macro builder, I have send object selected and filled out the relevant fields. However when the macro runs, an outlook prompt pops up with the message but doesn't send the email.

Comment: Which version of Outlook and operating system do you use?

Comment: Outlook 2007 and Windows 7, thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have stumbled on this once before with outlook 2007. In outlook 2007 there was a change from previous versions. The not so obvious thing was that it needed an installed antivirus to let go of the prompt that showed up. I just installed a free one but I think you have to use one that is recognized by windows. It must also be up to date with the virus definitions.

This is of course after you have disabled all security in Outlook preventing programatic access (which is the default setting), and I think you need administrator privileges on the computer also. I just post this here, it's so long ago that I'll have to check on the system later to be 100% shure.

Have a look at [this](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/I-get-warnings-about-a-program-accessing-e-mail-address-information-or-sending-e-mail-on-my-behalf-df007135-c632-4ae4-8577-dd4ba26750a2?CorrelationId=63cb971b-b4fa-4f78-aa02-1302d20f260e&ui=en-US&rs=en-AU&ad=AU) for some more information.